# LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT

Tags: debugging

I am trying to use the Debug API's to solve some specific problem and I track the LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT to be informed if a specific dll module is loaded, (the dll module actually is an exe  file).

I use:

```
GetModuleFileNameEx(
    hCurrentProcess, 
    (HMODULE)pDebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpBaseOfDll, 
    szModuleFileName, 
    sizeof(szModuleFileName) / sizeof(TCHAR)
);
```

in order to obtain the loaded module's filename.

To my surprise what I get instead are multiple references to cryptbase.dll being loaded, each on a different tid, but not the module in question.

I don't want to go the hard way of hooking cryptbase.dll and its associated import calls so is there an easier solution to obtain the loaded module's filename ?

Comment: Is there nothing in the `pDebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpImageName` member?

Comment: Attempting to query pDebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpImageName causes a crash.
The documentation states..
This member is strictly optional.  This member may be NULL, or it may contain the address of a string pointer in the address space of the process being debugged. That address may, in turn, either be NULL or point to the actual filename.
I.e. 
                            wsprintf(szText, L"Image Name: %s\n", pDebugEv->u.LoadDll.lpImageName);
                            OutputDebugString(szText)

Comment: It's an address in the debugee's address space (when not null).

Comment: Thanks, will check on that.